# Sandbox limitations for sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100 version and whenever I click on run code snippet button in stackoverflow.com, It is showing some error as shown in  following Image[image]

I have tried  the following setting from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067069/javascript-errors-localstorage-cookie-loading-sandboxed-iframe-within-chrome)

To fix the issue go to `Settings` > `Privacy` > `Content Settings` change the cookies settings to Allow local data to be set

But it didn't helped me ... How can I fix this error?

Comment: Update Chrome to Version 62.0.3202.75  but also it gives error

Comment: It seems that you are using `localStorage`; I don't think that it is possible to use it on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript errors (localstorage, cookie) loading sandboxed iframe within Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067069/javascript-errors-localstorage-cookie-loading-sandboxed-iframe-within-chrome)

Comment: @edkeveked I have gone through that, but was not able to fix that error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the `localStorage` in stackoverflow snippet. It is a matter of the `same origin policy`.

I found this explanation [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets)

> When the embedded document has the same origin as the main page, it is strongly discouraged to use both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin at the same time, as that allows the embedded document to programmatically remove the sandbox attribute. Although it is accepted, this case is no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute.